# Rails 4: savonrb > wasabi - Dependency conflict for mime-types version

Tags: mime-types, savon

I want to install the `savon` gem to parse some WSDLs. After including it in the Gemfile and running bundle install, it is giving the following message:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types":
  In Gemfile:
    savon (~> 2.8.0) ruby depends on
      wasabi (= 3.3.0) ruby depends on
        mime-types (< 2.0.0) ruby

    mail (>= 0) ruby depends on
      mime-types (2.4.3)
```

I can't remove the mail gem to resolve this dependency as my actionmailer depends on it. And besides, it doesn't seem to be healthy solution to resolve such dependency conflicts.

So can anyone help me on this? Googling didn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to **parse** a WSDL you could use the current version (3.3.1) of wasabi by itself, [which does not depend on the mime-types gem anymore](https://github.com/savonrb/wasabi/issues/48).

If you need savon, there is a [pending issue to update the dependency to the next minor version of wasabi, to resolve this issue](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/656). Since this has not happened yet, you may clone this repo, do it yourself (replace 3.3.0 with 3.3.1 in [this file](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/master/savon.gemspec)) and install your own version:

```
gem 'savon', github: 'xxx/myrepo'
```

until savon is updated.

Comment: I'll most probably wait for the update then, as i don't need it that urgently. Thanks for informing though.